# Encode opencv::Mat (grayscale) image to .jpg format and generate a byte[ ]

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing

I need some guidance to encode an OpenCV Mat image to .jpg format and create a byte array from that. This byte array will be used to recreate the original image using another application which does not have OpenCV library installed.

Basically, I need to create a byte array of a Mat image from a c++ appllication(OpenCV installed) and recreate it using a java app(no OpenCV).

so far I have tried,

```
        std::vector<uchar> buffer;
        cv::imencode(".jpg", returnImage, buffer);
        uchar * byteArray = buffer.data();
```

in here the `buffer` has large amount of values but `buffer.data()` contains only first few values from `buffer` and then "incomplete sequence\340".

I would like to convert Mat image to a byte[] without resaving it to the disk and the created byte array should be able to use in Java to recreate the original .jpg image.

any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: where does that "incomplete sequence" appear? Is it part of the byteArray? I don't see a problem in your code... Can you check the vector's uchar data, whether the same byte sequence is in it?

Comment: thanx.I have managed to fix the problem. yes, Vector<> contained all the bytes but the problem arose when assigning to " uchar * byteArray". I fixed the problem by returning the vector<> from the function without assigning it to uchar*.

Comment: The actual problem was the "std::vector<uchar> buffer" where it contained null termination characters inside it while decoding the .jpg file. so when "buffer.data()"  is called it only returned the elements until first null termination character.